# Array String en funcion es nulo

Tags: c#, array, csv, visual-studio-2019

Tengo una funcion que carga el una variable el array de retorno de la libreria TextFieldParser de c#, al ejecutar genera un error con lo siguiente:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Al ejecutar, todo sale bien, pero al dar click en el boton que llama la funcion de cargar se interrumpe y marca el error en "}" de cierre del for.

```
public string[] cargar()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Iniciando carga de datos, espere!!");
        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\Training.csv"))
        {
            csvReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)//cambios de lectura
            {

                try
                {
                    string linea = csvReader.ReadLine();
                    string[] fields = linea.Split(',');
                    for (int i = 0; i <= (fields.Length - 1); i++)
                    {
                        string temo = fields[i];
                        valv[i] = temo;
                    }
                    return valv;
                }
                catch(InvalidCastException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        return valv;
    }
```

La variable "valv" se encuntra declarada en la parte superior dentro de la clase, de la siguiente manera:

```
public string[] valv { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que la variable no ha sido inicializada, intenta algo como:

```
string[] valv = new string[tam];
```

Saludos.

Comment: en, efecto, soluciono el problema, dentro de la función!!, mil gracias